# How can I modify the Live CD to start into a live session ("try ubuntu") directly?

Tags: live-cd

I am creating a custom Ubuntu live CD built on 10.04.2. By default it boots up to a screen where you have two options, try without installation and install.

This is the step I would like to avoid: [image]

I would rather have it boot into the start up options screen, the one you can enter by hitting a key when first starting Ubuntu or just go straight to the desktop.

I would like to head here by default: [image]

Comment: The package responsible for the live installer is called `ubiquity`

Comment: GREAT question. One ive always asked myself.  Ive once set up a USB stick for my mon, to use Ubuntu for like 3 months (with a casper-rw of 4GB for changes). Skipping that screen nd boot straight to desktop would be awesome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up removing ubiquity and that made the live disk boot straight to the desktop.

```
apt-get purge ubiquity
```

Answer (score 0):

I use "Remastersys Backup" to make my custom live iso's. I then use Ubuntu's "Startup Disk Creator" to put the iso on to a USB stick. When I boot from it, it goes right to the desktop with an icon on the desktop to install it to the hard drive.
To try "Remastersys Backup", you'll need to add the following to your "sources.list"

deb http://www.geekconnection.org/remastersys/repository karmic/